# Number of ways to connect sets of $k$ dots in a perfect $n$-gon

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, combinations, polygons

Let $Q(n,k)$ be the number of ways in which we can connect sets of $k$ vertices in a given perfect $n$-gon such that no two lines intersect at the **interior** of the $n$-gon and no vertex remains isolated.

Intersection of the lines **outside** the $n$-gon is acceptable. Obviously, $k|n$, and $n$ *can't* be prime because otherwise there will be dots left unconnected. The $n$-gon itself is an acceptable solution to a connection of $n$ vertices, and in the case of $k>2$, these aren't lines, but a set of connected lines, a sort of a network formed by connected planar graphs with straight edges with $k$ vertices, which are required to be vertices of the $n$-gon itself.

There must always be $S =\frac nk$ sets of lines. For $k=2$, there are exactly $\frac nk$ lines, and for $k>2$, there are exactly $\frac nk$, not lines but sets of such connected planar graphs.

Take for example $Q(6,2)$. We have a perfect hexagon. By brute-forcing with pencil and paper, I found that there are 5 ways to connect sets of 2 vertices (dots) such that no two lines intersect inside the hexagon. Hence, $Q(6,2) = 5$.

The following image depicts the case of $Q(6,2)$:

[image: Q(6,2)]

I know for sure that an elegant solution exists for $k=2$, but I can't figure it out. For generality I ask about any amount of $k$ dots.

It's also extremely important to note we're not dividing the $n$-gon into $k$-gons, but connecting paths between $k$ nodes/vertices/dots.

#### Now let's move one step further:

Let $U(n,k)$ be the number of **unique** ways to connect sets of $k$ dots in a perfect $n$-gon, such that no two lines intersect, and **rotational symmetry** is neglected, i.e, every possible arrangement is unique and can't be formed by rotating or flipping another arrangement in any way. $U(6,2)=2$.
Note that $U(6,2)=2$ because the arrangements of the first line in the image are not unique, and can be formed by rotating one another. The same happens for the second line of arrangements. This results in only 1 unique arrangement for each line. Hence $U(6,2)=2$.

I'm pretty clueless about both functions $U$ and $Q$, and I couldn't derive an algorithm or formula to any of them. Hence I'm posting this here.

I'm pretty sure there's a pure combinatorial approach to this problem, perhaps involving Polya's Enumeration Theorem (PET). Is there an elegant solution to these functions? Can they even be solved for $k>2$?

Any light shed on any of the functions will be very much appreciable, as I haven't been successful in deriving a formula for any of them.

#### EDIT - Temporary Solutions + Relevant questions AND progress

$$Q(n,2) = C_{n \over 2}\quad\text{where}\quad C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$
And $C_n$ denotes the $n$'th **Catalan** number.

Now let us denote $W(n) = U(n,2)$. Can you find a formula for $W(n)$? Perhaps a connection between $Q(n,2)$ and $W(n)$?

**Another EDIT: (2)**

$$Q(k,k) = k\cdot 2^{k-3}$$

**EDIT 3**

It seems like in general, $Q(n,3)$ is given here:
https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C27%2C324&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Perhaps generalization to higher powers will result in the general $Q(n,k)$ function..

**EDIT 4**

Here is a small table of values for $Q(n,k)$, which seems to be correct, provided by **fabian**'s algorithm:
(Table is in the form $Q(x\cdot k,k)$)

$$
\begin{array}{c|rrrrr}
{_k\,\backslash\, ^n} & k & 2k & 3k & 4k & 5k \\
\hline
2 & 1  & 2     & 5       & 14         & 42\\
3 & 3  & 27    & 324     & 4455       & 66339\\
4 & 8  & 256   & 11264   & 573440     & 31752192\\
5 & 20 & 2000  & 280000  & 45600000   & 8096000000\\
6 & 48 & 13824 & 5640192 & 2686058496 & 1396580548608\\
\end{array}
$$

**EDIT 5 - $Q(n,k)$ *SOLVED***

As beautifully found and explained by **@CuddlyCuttlefish** in his answer, the formula for $Q(n,k)$ is as follows:
$$Q(n,k) = \frac{(n)_{\frac{n}{k}-1}}{\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)!}\cdot (k\cdot 2^{k-3})^{\frac{n}{k}} \quad\text{where}\quad (n)_j = n(n-1)...(n-(j-1))$$

And $(n)_j$ is the **falling factorial**, defined as above.

### Now moving to $U(n,k)$

Now it only remains to find a formula or an algorithm for $U(n,k)$.
Personally I think it has to do with **Polya's Enumeration Theorem** and **Burnside's lemma**, combined with the **cycle-index of the symmetric group**, $Z(S_n)$. I've touched upon something related to that, and thus I think it's related. I'm not 100% sure but my instincts tell me it's related.

**EDIT 6**

In order to make it clear, I'm hereby adding a picture to describe the case of $U(6,3)$ and by that to clarify better what $U(n,k)$ means.

[image]

$U(6,3)=4$, as shown in the picture above (@**Marko Riedel** has pointed out an additional arrangement which I had previously missed). There are four **unique** arrangements to connect sets of 3 vertices such that **no vertice remains isolated, no lines intersect at the interior of the hexagon, and each arrangement is unique and can't be formed by rotating or flipping any other arrangement.**

There are two unique **path-types**, one that is introduced by connecting 3 adjacent vertices ($p_1$), and another that connects 2 vertices with a little **"jump",** and the third vertice is then adjacent ($p_2$).

Hope it makes things a bit clearer..

**EDIT 7**

As provided by @**Marko Riedel's** algorithm, $U(n,3)$ sequence starts as follows:

$$1, 4, 22, 201, 2244, 29096, 404064, 5915838,\ldots$$

Computation was very rough, and calculation times were long. That's about as efficient as it gets, as of now. Producing more values just consumes either too much memory, time or both. Refer to **Marko Riedel's** answers for more sequences and further explanations. Also if anybody can verify the above it would be great.

Comment: Have you calculated first values for W(n) and checked OEIS for this sequence?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff No, I have not. Brute-forcing gets extremely exhaustive. Too exhaustive to do on paper. I might be able to get the first 2-3 values of it by hand but no further.

Comment: Have you considered posting this on [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta No, I haven't even known about this variant of stackexchange. Do you think I should post a copy there as well?

Comment: Yeah it seems more relevant.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42909/number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-vertices-in-a-perfect-n-gon done :D

Comment: This may be related: https://oeis.org/A183758; this includes rotations but not flips: https://oeis.org/A183757.

Comment: Could somebody make a table of $Q(n,k)$ for some small $n,k$? That always helps to formulate conjectures (with the aid of oeis).

Comment: @barto Hi there ! I'll get onto it very soon, in the next (2-3) few hours, and will also update progress of the problem. Meanwhile refer to CuddlyCuttlefish answer, it is correct as far as we know! Only left to find something more "efficient", perhaps purely combinatorial and not recursion-dependant. The generalised Catalan numbers look quite promising. $U(n,k)$ is still unsolved though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24089/discussion-on-question-by-matan-number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-dots-in-a).

Comment: @barto I finally had some time, and put a table with a few values of $Q(n,k)$. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Matan: I'm afraid it's not appropriate to put an "UNSOLVED" message in the title. The fact that there is currently not an accepted answer means the post is already considered unsolved.

Comment: @Matan I still like this question, but I don't agree with trivial edits (like italicizing select words, for example). I suspected, and Marco Riedel confirmed, that this is an open problem; i.e., *nobody* can sit down and write out a full answer (as such a thing could easily turn into a paper in a journal, currently). What do you hope to accomplish by bumping the post like this?

Comment: As I have previously mentioned, *I do not think* this is an open problem, but rather a very difficult one, which some people might know how to solve using combinatorics. See that $Q(n,k)$ **has** been solved. I think it requires some innovative, substantial thinking as well as research and knowledge. I'm myself dedicating considerable amount of time to solve this. What I thus hope to achieve by bumping the post is more readers, as I truly believe a solution exists. I don't have any other way.. With that being said, I'm aware it's inappropriate, and will lessen or stop the edits. Sorry. @pjs36

Answer (score 6):

We can count the number of partitions described above by first dividing the $n$-gon into non-intersecting $k$-gons, then creating the $k$-paths within the $k$-gons.

The number of decompositions of an $n$-gon into $\frac{n}{k}$ non-intersecting partitions of size $k$ is
$$Q'(n,k) = \frac{(n)_{\frac{n}{k}-1}}{\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)!}$$
Where $(n)_j$ is the falling factorial. This is a specific case of a result of [Kreweras (in translation)](http://www.math.msu.edu/~earnshaw/research/kreweras.pdf).

Now, within each $k$-gon, we can start at any of $k$-vertices (k choices) and create a non-intersecting path by proceeding clockwise or counter-clockwise to the nearest vertex in the $k$-gon (2 choices) with the last vertex forced. This will count each path twice, as a valid path can begin from either of its two ends. This yields

$$\frac{k2^{k-2}}{2} = k2^{k-3}$$

Ways to create a valid path inside the $k$-gon (see @fabian's answer for the original explanation).

Then for each $n$-gon, we have $\frac{n}{k}$ distinct $k$-gons with which to make the paths, giving

$$(k2^{k-3})^{\frac{n}{k}}$$

valid path configurations for each $k$-gon configuration. Combining the two results gives

$$Q(n,k) = (k2^{k-3})^{\frac{n}{k}} \times Q'(n,k) = (k2^{k-3})^{\frac{n}{k}}\frac{(n)_{\frac{n}{k}-1}}{\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)!}$$

Comment: Suppose $W(n)=U(n,2)$  and that $T(n)=Q(n,2)=C(\frac n2)$  where $C(n)$  is the $n$'th catalan number. Do you have any suggestion as to what is the formula for $W(n)$? Perhaps a connection between $W(n)$  and $T(n)$? I think it's related to the dihedral group, as mentioned in another answer. Perhaps Polya's enumeration theorem as I stated. How do we neglect the rotational symmetry?

Comment: As @pjs36 wrote, this is similar to another open problem, and so I think it's unlikely that there is a neat solution to this variant either.

Comment: While I'm not sure my problem is solvable for $k>2$, I think $W(n)$ can be solved, because I know that the topic of "neglecting rotational symmetry" is not 'open', and rather there exists a solution to this, involving cycle-index and PET as well as Burnside's lemma. I have myself solved a (very) few problems regarding this subject, which were very difficult.. I think $W(n)$ is solvable, Only I don't know how to solve it. Working on it now. Thanks !

Comment: Hey, I wanted to try your recurrence, now that I had time, but I don't understand it. Could you explain the $Q(n,3)$? What is $i$? what is $j$? The index of the sum, its starting value and last value are not clear to me, sorry. Could you explain please?

Comment: Also, I believe $Q(k,k)=1$ is wrong. Take for example $Q(3,3)$. There are 3 ways to connect them: 1->2->3 , 1->3->2 , 2->1->3. And in general, $Q(k,k) = k\cdot 2^{k-3}$. Please refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414804/number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-vertices-in-a-perfect-n-gon to see an algorithm posted by someone, where he explains how to calculate $Q(n,k)$. I myself couldn't derive the formula of this recurrence. Can you?

Comment: I see - we're connecting paths. Somehow, I was thinking that we were grouping it into $k$-gons, not paths of length $k$.

Comment: Yeah, it's sets of paths of length $k$, not $k$ gons. It's difficult to explain it, I tried my best in the question. Can we chat? How do I open a chat? lol.

Comment: The sum ranges over vertices in the graph. To make my answer match, it will work to simply multiply it by the $k2^{k-3}$ factor after completing the summation.

Comment: No idea how the chat works :P. As it stands, my recurrence counts the number of ways to decompose the polygon into sets of $k$ vertices. I think it may actually be more effective to count this before applying an ordering. I'll edit my post to take note of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24083/discussion-between-cuddlycuttlefish-and-matan).

Comment: There seems to be a little mistake in the formula. Tried to spot it and replace a few of the terms but no luck. It gives for example $Q(3,3)=27$ instead of 3. $Q(9,3) = 1134$ instead of 324. In general it seems like $Q(n,3)$ can be found here: https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C27%2C324&sort=&language=english&go=Search
Can you spot the error in the formula, @CuddlyCuttlefish ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the calculation on the recursive formula for that problem.

You can observe the following:

- we don't need to restrict ourselfs to regular polygons, the numbers remain the same, if strictly convex polygons are used.
- there are $k \cdot 2^{k-3}$ ways to combine $k$ nodes to paths such that no line on the path crosses another line of the path (choose the starting point ($k$ possibilities), then you can choose $k-2$ times, if the next node is the next node not already on the path clockwise or counterclockwise from the start node; That makes $k \cdot 2^{k-2}$ paths, but every path was counted exactly twice)

  #### Example with 6 nodes:

  All those paths start at the rightmost node. We start with all choosing all nodes to be the next node counterclockwise from the start node (0000), then "count up" to choosing all nodes to be the next node counter-clockwise from the start node (1111); (0001 means choosing the first node to be the next node counter-clockwise from the start node and all the rest to be the next node clockwise from the start node)

  [image: 16 possible paths starting at node 1 for 6 nodes]

  Note that all those paths are different, but if we use all nodes as starting nodes, then the path using the end node as start node and the start node as end node and connecting the same nodes cannot be distinguished in the end, since paths are not directed. E.g. the first path would be the same as the last path with start and end point exchanged.
- The number of nodes that can be "skipped" between nodes on one path can only be a multiple of $k$
- Graphs can be recursively constructed like this: choose $k$ nodes, such that there are only multipes of $k$ between 2 neighboring nodes, if enumerated clockwise (whole polygon). Choose any way to connect those nodes to a path $p$ such that the lines don't intersect. For each of the $k$ (possibly empty) sets of nodes between nodes on $p$ if enumerated clockwise(whole polygon) recursively construct the paths.
- The recursive definition of $Q$ is:

  $Q(n, k) = k \cdot 2^{k-3} \cdot\sum\limits_{\substack{p_1, p_2, ..., p_{k-1} \in \mathbb{N}\\p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_{k-1} \leq n/k-1}} Q(k \cdot(n/k-1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} p_i), k) \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} Q(p_i \cdot k, k)$

  $Q(0, k) = 1$

This is a dynamic programming approach to calculate $Q(n, k)$ (called like this: `new PolygonLinesCombinations(k).getResult(n)`)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PolygonLinesCombinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new PolygonLinesCombinations(Integer.parseInt(args[1]))
                .getResult(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    }

    public PolygonLinesCombinations(int k) {
        if (k < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("k >= 2 expected, but found " + k);
        }
        this.k = k;
        this.results = new ArrayList<>();
        this.kDec = k - 1;
        this.factor = planarLineNumber(k);
        this.partition = new int[kDec];

        // exactly 1 way to connect 0 nodes
        this.results.add(BigInteger.ONE);

        // exactly 1 way to choose the rest
        this.results.add(this.factor);
    }

    private final int k;
    private final BigInteger factor;
    private final int kDec;
    private final ArrayList<BigInteger> results;
    private final int[] partition;

    public BigInteger getResult(int n) {
        if ((n % this.k) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n is not divisible by k; n=" + n + ";k=" + k);
        }

        // calculate all missing results with increasing n
        int m = n / k;
        for (int i = results.size(); i <= m; i++) {
            results.add(calculateResult(i));
        }
        return results.get(m);
    }

    private BigInteger calculateResult(int m) {
        // nodes remaining, after this set is chosen
        int remainingPartitions = m - 1;
        Arrays.fill(partition, 0);

        BigInteger possibilities = BigInteger.ZERO;

        int sum = 0;
        do {
            // number of possiblities for this partition
            // = product of the number of possibilities for each remaining part
            BigInteger possibilitiesForPartition = this.factor;
            for (int i = 0; i < kDec; i++) {
                possibilitiesForPartition = possibilitiesForPartition.multiply(results.get(partition[i]));
            }
            possibilities = possibilities.add(
                    possibilitiesForPartition.multiply(results.get(remainingPartitions - sum)));

            // generate next ordered partition
            for (int i = 0; i < kDec; i++) {
                partition[i]++;
                sum++;
                if (sum > remainingPartitions) {
                    // reset to 0, if a partition gets too large
                    sum -= partition[i];
                    partition[i] = 0;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (sum > 0); // stop, if all-zeroes partition is reached again

        return possibilities;
    }

    // returns n * 2^(n-3)
    private static BigInteger planarLineNumber(int k) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(k).shiftLeft(k - 3);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to test the code on eclipse to see if it matches some of my brute-force findings. However, it immediately and constantly threw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions. I couldn't locate the bug myself. It may be something very minor. Could you take a look?

Comment: @Matan: Did you pass `n` and `k` as command line parameters. You have to do that or rewrite the main method (and get `n` and `k` some other way). When I tested it, it successfully calculated `Q(6, 2) = 5` and `Q(6, 3) = 27`. Hint: if you want to calculate multiple `Q`s for the same `k`, don't throw the reference to the `PolygonLinesCombinations` away, because it keeps the intermediate results already calculated.

Comment: I will try to get them some other way. Also, the memoization/caching is clear to me. However, Q(6,3) = 4. It can't possibly be 27. Remember that no vertice my be left unconnected, and that the graphs may not intersect inside the hexagon. 27 isn't possible. Try Q(6,3) for yourself, you'll see there are only 4 possible arrangements.

Comment: @Matan: Well, I tried it out and I still believe 27 is the correct result for `Q(6, 3)`: You'll have to come up with 2 paths. The following combinations of vertices on the paths are allowed: `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`, `{{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}` and `{{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}`. Each 3-node set can be arranged as path in 3 ways: `(1st, 2nd, 3rd)`, `(1st, 3rd, 2nd)` and `(2nd, 1st, 3rd)`, which results in `3^3 = 27` ways to connect them.

Comment: You are.. correct sir. I was foolishly mistaken :). many kudos ! will try a few more results.

Comment: I've tested a few more values, both on paper and with your algorithm. Not only I got identical results with both, but also the combinatorial approach your algorithm suggests seems correct and efficient, with no exhaustive mechanisms. Are you able to derive a formula/algorithm for    U(n,k)? even U(n,2)?

Comment: I believe that the value $k 2^(k-3)$ is incorrect. The number of ways to group $k$ points into a non-crossing polygon where the order of the vertices matter (though I don't think it should :P) is the size of the symmetry group $|D_{k}|  = 2k$. Additionally, it's not clear why you count different orderings of the vertices of a polygon {1,2,3} $\neq$ {1,3,2}, but not of a line {1,2} = {2,1}, in this scheme.

Comment: And do not that each 3-node set can actually be arranged in any of the following 6 ways: 123, 321, 231, 132, 213, 312.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: The order matters, since you can find the starting point of a path therefore you can enumerate the nodes along the path. But you have to divide by 2, since you'll enumerate the path both in forward and backward direction and those should be the same (Your 3-node example: `123` and `321` are the same). Therefore of the 6 ways you listed only 3 are destinguishable in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Put $T_n = Q(n, 2)$ and taking $T_0 = 0$ by convention. Then the $T_n$ are odd when $n$ is odd and the values for even $n$ satisfy the following recursion equations:

$$
\begin{align*}
T_0 &= 1 \\
T_2 &= 1 \\
T_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{n/2}T_{2(i-1)} \cdot T_{2(n/2-i)}
\end{align*}
$$

To see this, enumerate the vertices of the $n$-gon as $v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}$,  A solution with a connected pair $(v_i, v_j)$ with $i < j$ has to have $j -i$ odd and for $i < s < j$, $v_t$ must be connected to some $v_t$ where $i < t < j$. Thus we can connect $v_0$ to $v_1$ or $v_3$ or $v_5$ and so on. When we connect $v_0$ to $v_{2i+1}$ we get two instances of the same problem with $n$ replaced by $n'$ say, one with $n' = 2(i-1)$ and one with $n'=2(n/2-i)$. This gives:

$$T_4 = 2, T_6 = 5, T_8 = 14, T_{10} = 42$$

And (once you do the sums right $\ddot{\frown}$), these turn out as pointed out by CuddyCuttlefish to be the Catalan numbers:http://oeis.org/A000108.

Comment: I think your recurrence is mis-indexed. Try using the sum form on $T_2$, and it gives 0. I believe it should start at $i=0$.

Comment: Was about to say the same thing. I think you should start from $i=2$ though. If started with $i=1$ it will constantly produce $0$ for every term.

Comment: But wait - shouldn't a connected pair have $j-i$ odd? Connect vertices $1$ and $2$. $2-1=1$, and the is definitely a valid connection to make.

Comment: Connecting $v_3$ to $v_5$ isolates vertex $v_4$ from ever making a connection.

Comment: And I believe that the reccurence form requires $T_0=1$. Suppose we start by connecting $v_{i}$ and $v_{i+1}$. This gives us a $T_{n-2}\times T_0$, and it can definitely lead a valid solution, while $T_0=0$ would discard this.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Made the function $T(n) = Q(n,2)$ exactly as Rob, with initial condition $T(0) = 1$ instead of $0$, and I got $T(10) = 42$, not $26$. This agrees with the 5th catalan number.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: I was in a hurry writing this up. It now says something more like what I meant. Please explain why it is wrong, as it still doesn't agree with the Catalan numbers.

Comment: It's not the indexing; rather, $T_0=0$ is not true. If $T_0$ = 0, then your recurrence gives $T_n=0$ for all $n$.  With your recurrence, $T_2 = T_0T_0 = 0$.

Comment: @RobArthan I wrote the function, as I said, exactly like yours, with the only difference beiing $T_0=1$ in Mathematica. And it gives me $T_{10}=42$, not $26$, and 42 is the 5th $(\frac {10}2)$ catalan number

Comment: I still really like your solution, really explains the algorithm behind solving this :)

Comment: @Matan: thanks the kind words and helping me get the description right.

Comment: No problem! Can you take a look at the edits I made to the question at its very bottom? Maybe you can help me figure a formula for $W(n)$?

Answer (score 2):

Adapting to the changes in the question (which I do hope has stablized now and which I interpret to mean dihedral symmetry on the vertices of the polygon with three undirected possible paths in every hyperedge on three vertices) I get for $U(n,3)$ the sequence
$$1, 4, 22, 201, 2244, 29096,404064,\ldots$$

This has a value of four rather than three when $n=6$ with one configuration that is missing from the diagram that appeared an hour ago. I nonetheless believe this to be the correct value. The missing configuration is the configuration consisting of two arrows with the tips pointing in opposite directions. Be sure to record this if you change the diagram now.

This was the Maple code for this computation with memoization turned off which is slower but does not consume as much memory.

```
with(combinat);

Q := (n,k)-> binomial(n,n/k-1)/(n/k)*(k*2^(k-3))^(n/k);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;

bs_ngon_edgeconfl :=
proc(t1, t2)
    local e1, e2, c, seg;

    e1 := {op(1, t1)} union op(2, t1);
    e2 := {op(1, t2)} union op(2, t2);

    if nops(e1 union e2) <> 6 then return true fi;

    seg := [];

    for c to 3 do
        if op(1, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(2, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 1]
        elif op(2, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(3, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 2]
        else
            seg := [op(seg), 3];
        fi;
    od;

    evalb(not(seg[1] = seg[2] and seg[2] = seg[3]));
end;

bs_ngon_cycconfl :=
proc(c)
    # option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c) do
        for q from p+1 to nops(c) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c[p], c[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_cyc2confl :=
proc(c1, c2)
    # option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c1) do
        for q to nops(c2) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c1[p], c2[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_recurse :=
proc(n, cycs, pos, sofar, len)
    local res, p;

    if 3*len > n then return 0 fi;

    if pos > nops(cycs) then
        if 3*len = n then
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    res := bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1, sofar, len);

    for p to nops(sofar) do
        if bs_ngon_cyc2confl(cycs[sofar[p]], cycs[pos]) then
            break;
        fi;
    od;

    if p = nops(sofar) + 1 then
        res :=
        res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1,
                              [op(sofar), pos],
                              len+nops(cycs[pos]));
    fi;

    res;
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges_src, e, edges, autom,
    cycles, p, res;

    if type(n mod 3, positive) then return 0 fi;

    edges_src := convert(choose({seq(p, p=0..n-1)}, 3), list);

    edges := [];
    for e in edges_src do
        edges := [op(edges),
                  {e[3], {e[1], e[2]}},
                  {e[2], {e[1], e[3]}},
                  {e[1], {e[2], e[3]}}];
    od;

    res := Q(n, 3);
    # res := 0;

    for rot from 0 to n-1 do
        if rot > 0 then
            autom :=
            [seq({edges[p][1]+rot mod n,
                  {edges[p][2][1]+rot mod n,
                   edges[p][2][2]+rot mod n}},
                 p=1..nops(edges))];

            cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
            cycles :=
            select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

            res := res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycles, 1, [], 0);
        fi;

        autom :=
        [seq({n-1-(edges[p][1]+rot) mod n,
              {n-1-(edges[p][2][1]+rot) mod n,
               n-1-(edges[p][2][2]+rot) mod n}},
             p=1..nops(edges))];

        cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
        cycles :=
        select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

        res := res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycles, 1, [], 0);
    od;

    res/2/n;
end;
```

Comment: I've just updated the question and picture to include this additional configuration you mentioned.I thought it was clear that dihedral symmetry was the discussed symmetry type. Since it's an invented question I've come up with, then if you can derive a formula just for rotations then it would be great too. I do not know what's possible to find and what isn't, which is the reason I've shared this from the first place. I want the flips to be counted as well, but if it can't be done then just rotations is fine too. Finally, can you explain your algorithm? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this very interesting problem. I suggest we submit the sequence for $U(n,3)$ to the OEIS. This is an effective way to present it to some very sophisticated people and obtain useful feedback. The OEIS entry would include a link to this discussion page as well as as a pointer that with only eight terms a better algorithm is needed to extend the sequence. BTW it would be helpful if someone were to verify the value for $U(9,3) = 22$ which ought to be doable on paper or by total enumeration in software (not necessarily using Burnside).

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a "long(ish) comment" than an answer, and these are mostly my instincts speaking. But, I come bearing references!

While I won't say there's a *direct* connection between this and the Catalan numbers, I do suspect there is a connection, particularly involving the [generalized Catalan numbers](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~cossey/636papers/hilton%20and%20pedersen.pdf) which count the ways to subdivide regular $n$-gons into $(k + 1)$-gons (Note: this isn't my field, so the variables in my description don't match what's used in the article). I don't claim there is any sort of bijection, but I imagine similar techniques could be used for both.

It is a very open problem to count the number of orbits of polygon subdivisions under the action of the dihedral group, which is what your $U(n, k)$ reminds me of. Here's [a paper](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~cossey/636papers/moon%20and%20moser.pdf) by Moon and Moser on orbits of triangulations of $n$-gons from several decades ago, and here are two recent theses ([[1]](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~cossey/636papers/auger%20thesis.pdf) and [[2]](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~cossey/636papers/mott%20thesis.pdf)) on orbits of more general subdivisions under the action of the dihedral group.

Again, I don't claim that these will even be related - but they are investigations of a similar nature that are essentially wide open and definitely research-level. Further, I think the polygonal dissections have a bit more structure than what you're investigating, for better or worse.

Comment: Suppose $W(n)=U(n,2)$ and that $T(n)=Q(n,2)=C(\frac n2)$ where $C(n)$ is the $n$'th catalan number. Do you have any suggestion as to what is the formula for $W(n)$? Perhaps a connection between $W(n)$ and $T(n)$?

Comment: @Matan I will definitely think about this, even though I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark.** What follows refers to the first version of the question,
which did not include dihedral symmetry.

I  computed  $U(n,2)$ and  $U(n,3)$  (rotational  symmetry) which  was
enough to  find the relevant entries  at the OEIS where  we learn that
this is indeed an active area of  research but we also learn and I ask
the reader  to reflect  on this, that  the way  we are looking  at the
problem here is not quite optimal and it is much better to think about
it in terms of trees. I am posting my computation for the record as to
how I found  the correct values to query the OEIS  and might return to
this at some other time. I  would like to stress that the OEIS entries
have simple formulae  and detailed references for all  of this. A trip
to the library is in order.

We can use Burnside to  compute these. The permutation group is the
action of  the cyclic group  on the vertices  acting on the  edges. We
enumerate these permutations by applying the vertex permutations to an
ordered list of  the edges / hyperedges and  factoring the result into
cycles. Edges can be either on or  off and we must count the number of
admissible  assignments that are  fixed by  the permutation  for later
averaging  by the  order of  the group.   Because the  status  must be
constant  on  the cycles  we  turn  off /  turn  on  entire cycles  at
once. Cycles that  contain edges that cross or share  a vertex must be
in the  off state. The  remaining cycles can  be turned on or  off but
only  as long  as there  are  no conflicts  between them  (overlapping
hyperedges). I  used a backtracking  search to count  admissible cycle
combinations.  Finally I point  out that  the identity  permutation is
special  here as  it fixes  all admissible  assignments and  hence its
contribution  to   the  Burnside  average  is  the   total  number  of
assignments  with  no symmetry  acting  on  then,  i.e.  $Q(n,2)$  and
$Q(n,3)$ which are

$$\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{2n+1}{3n\choose n}.$$

This produced the  following sequence for $U(n,2)$ ($n$  even) using a
reasonable combination of time / space resources 
$$1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 14, 34, 95, 280, 854, 2694, 8714,\ldots$$

This is [OEIS  A002995](https://oeis.org/A002995) and that entry gives
an  impression of  the  amount of  research  that has  gone into  this
sequence.

The Maple code was as follows.

```
CAT := n -> 1/(n+1)*binomial(2*n,n);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;

bs_ngon_edgeconfl :=
proc(e1, e2)
    local c;

    if nops(e1 union e2) <> 4 then return true fi;

    c := 0;

    if op(1, e1) < op(1, e2) and
    op(1, e2) < op(2, e1) then
        c := c+1;
    fi;

    if op(1, e1) < op(2, e2) and
    op(2, e2) < op(2, e1) then
        c := c+1;
    fi;

    evalb(c = 1);
end;

bs_ngon_cycconfl :=
proc(c)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c) do
        for q from p+1 to nops(c) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c[p], c[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_cyc2confl :=
proc(c1, c2)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c1) do
        for q to nops(c2) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c1[p], c2[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_recurse :=
proc(n, cycs, pos, sofar, len)
    local res, p;

    if 2*len > n then return 0 fi;

    if pos > nops(cycs) then
        if 2*len = n then
            return 1
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    res := bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1, sofar, len);

    for p to nops(sofar) do
        if bs_ngon_cyc2confl(cycs[sofar[p]], cycs[pos]) then
            break;
        fi;
    od;

    if p = nops(sofar) + 1 then
        res :=
        res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1,
                              [op(sofar), pos],
                              len+nops(cycs[pos]));
    fi;

    res;
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges, autom, cycles, p, q, res;

    if type(n, odd) then return 0 fi;

    edges := [seq(seq({p,q}, q=p+1..n-1), p=0..n-1)];
    res := CAT(n/2);

    for rot to n-1 do
        autom :=
        [seq({edges[p][1]+rot mod n, edges[p][2]+rot mod n},
             p=1..nops(edges))];

        cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
        cycles :=
        select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

        res := res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycles, 1, [], 0);
    od;

    res/n;
end;
```

For  $U(n,3)$ we  obtain the  following  sequence ($n$  a multiple  of
three), again using a reasonable combination of time / space resources
$$1, 1, 2, 7, 19, 86, 372, 1825, 9143,\ldots$$

This is  [OEIS A054423](https://oeis.org/A054423), once  more an entry
with considerable activity.

This was the Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

CAT3 := n -> 1/(2*n+1)*binomial(3*n,n);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;

bs_ngon_edgeconfl :=
proc(e1, e2)
    local c, seg;

    if nops(e1 union e2) <> 6 then return true fi;

    seg := [];

    for c to 3 do
        if op(1, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(2, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 1]
        elif op(2, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(3, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 2]
        else
            seg := [op(seg), 3];
        fi;
    od;

    evalb(not(seg[1] = seg[2] and seg[2] = seg[3]));
end;

bs_ngon_cycconfl :=
proc(c)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c) do
        for q from p+1 to nops(c) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c[p], c[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_cyc2confl :=
proc(c1, c2)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c1) do
        for q to nops(c2) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c1[p], c2[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_recurse :=
proc(n, cycs, pos, sofar, len)
    local res, p;

    if 3*len > n then return 0 fi;

    if pos > nops(cycs) then
        if 3*len = n then
            return 1
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    res := bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1, sofar, len);

    for p to nops(sofar) do
        if bs_ngon_cyc2confl(cycs[sofar[p]], cycs[pos]) then
            break;
        fi;
    od;

    if p = nops(sofar) + 1 then
        res :=
        res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1,
                              [op(sofar), pos],
                              len+nops(cycs[pos]));
    fi;

    res;
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar3 :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges, autom, cycles, p, res;

    if type(n mod 3, positive) then return 0 fi;

    edges := convert(choose({seq(p, p=0..n-1)}, 3), list);
    res := CAT3(n/3);

    for rot to n-1 do
        autom :=
        [seq({edges[p][1]+rot mod n, 
              edges[p][2]+rot mod n,
              edges[p][3]+rot mod n},
             p=1..nops(edges))];

        cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
        cycles :=
        select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

        res := res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycles, 1, [], 0);
    od;

    res/n;
end;
```

**Addendum.** As per the comments I was definitely counting polygons and not paths. However this appears to be a simple matter of adding in factor of $3^\mathrm{len}$ to the backtracking search engine when a decomposition into polygons is found. This produces the sequence
$$3, 9, 54, 567, 4617, 62694, 813564, 11973825,\ldots$$
which does not have an OEIS entry yet. The Maple code here is the same as before except for the following changes:

```
Q := (n,k)-> binomial(n,n/k-1)/(n/k)*(k*2^(k-3))^(n/k);

bs_ngon_recurse :=
proc(n, cycs, pos, sofar, len)
    local res, p;

    if 3*len > n then return 0 fi;

    if pos > nops(cycs) then
        if 3*len = n then
            return 3^len
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    res := bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1, sofar, len);

    for p to nops(sofar) do
        if bs_ngon_cyc2confl(cycs[sofar[p]], cycs[pos]) then
            break;
        fi;
    od;

    if p = nops(sofar) + 1 then
        res :=
        res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycs, pos+1,
                              [op(sofar), pos],
                              len+nops(cycs[pos]));
    fi;

    res;
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges, autom, cycles, p, res;

    if type(n mod 3, positive) then return 0 fi;

    edges := convert(choose({seq(p, p=0..n-1)}, 3), list);
    res := Q(n, 3);

    for rot to n-1 do
        autom :=
        [seq({edges[p][1]+rot mod n,
              edges[p][2]+rot mod n,
              edges[p][3]+rot mod n},
             p=1..nops(edges))];

        cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
        cycles :=
        select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

        res := res + bs_ngon_recurse(n, cycles, 1, [], 0);
    od;

    res/n;
end;
```

**Addendum II.** Using the same algorithm as above (which I can post if desired) I get the following values for $U(n,4):$ $$8, 64, 1536, 45056, 1703936, 80478208,\ldots$$ which I hope can serve to verify the correctness of a better algorithm that might appear in this discussion.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you reply and effort. I too agree that the way we're looking at the problem is not optimal. This is also reflected by other answers here which were based on other visualizations of the problem, such as handshakes, trees, parantheses and others. Now, although your $Q(n,2)$ is correct, I suspect your $Q(n,3)$ is not, also because it gives different results than other formulas here. This could perhaps result in wrong $U(n,3)$. Note we're not dividing the $n$-gon into $k$-gons, but rather paths of length $k$.

Comment: As for $W(n)=U(n,2)$ I think the sequence is correct, as it also agrees with my some of pencil & paper values for small $n$. I've got Maple but I haven't had time to test the code yet. Do you think it can be generalized to $U(n,k)$? Do you think it can even be solved generally for all $k$?
Finally, can you write a mathematical formula for $U(n,k)$ or $W(n)=U(n,2)$ so translation of the code to other languages will be possible? I will once again thank you for your research and effort you put into this. and I will appreciate your response.

Comment: I understand what you mean, please consult my above addendum for a count of 3-paths rather than triangles. As for closed formulae, like I said above, a trip to the library may be in order. The OEIS entries have simple formulae suitable for porting to other languages. You might want to add $U(n,3)$ to the OEIS. I can do $U(n,4)$ but I will get fewer terms because the number of edges is quadratic.

Comment: It still looks a bit weird. $U(3,3)=1$. Draw 3 points and number them clockwise starting with the top left as 1. Now connect them. You will get 3 results, which correspond to $Q(3,3)=3$: {1->2->3}, {1->3->2}, {2->1->3}. However, each one can be formed by rotating the other two, and thus they only account for **one** unique arrangement, resulting in: $U(3,3)=1$. Next comment for $U(6,3)=3$ due to lack of characters..

Comment: Another example is $U(6,3)=3$. The 3 unique arrangements are: {{1->2->3}, {4->5->6}}, {{1->2->6}, {3->4->5}} and {{1->5->6}, {2->4->3}}. This is due to the existence of only 2 unique paths $p_1$ & $p_2$, giving the following 3 combinations of them: {$p_1$,$p_1$}, {$p_2$, $p_2$} and {$p_1$,$p_2$}.

Comment: If I have a decomposition of the cycle into n/k non-intersecting k-gons then how many decompositions into k-paths can I obtain from it and how? What operation do I apply to the k-gons? What criterion defines admissible k-paths and when are they isomorphic?

Comment: Well, in $Q(n,k)$ the order in which the paths are drawn is important, but in $U(n,k)$ it is not. It's easy to see that it $Q(3,3)$ all the 3 paths are isomorphic, and therefore count as 1 unique path in $U$. Other than that, all paths are admissible, as long as they don't intersect with one another. Note that the paths are of length $k-1$ and they connect $k$ vertices.

Comment: For $U(6,3)$ we get two triangles on three adjacent vertices as the only non-ismorphic configuration (one configuration) as the rotations transform them into each other. However, aren't there three paths of length two per triangle rather than two as you say?

Comment: Refer to my last edit to see $U(6,3)$, and see what $U(n,k)$ means. I hope I explain it well there, and I also added a picture to show it. I think it should clarify things.

Comment: I did not realize you were including flips in your transformations. That changes the group from the cyclic group to the dihedral group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24306/discussion-between-matan-and-marko-riedel).

Answer (score 1):

By introducing parallelism into the algorithm for $U(n,3)$ using the Maple **task** parallel programming framework I was able to compute another value from the sequence, which now reads $$1, 4, 22, 201, 2244, 29096, 404064, 5915838,\ldots$$ It is hoped that these values can serve to verify a more sophisticated algorithm if and when it appears. Peak usage was 18 processors at 2GHz with about 60 minutes computation time and max memory allocation 4.6GB.

This was the Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

Q := (n,k)-> binomial(n,n/k-1)/(n/k)*(k*2^(k-3))^(n/k);

pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1; data := [];

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
            data := [op(data), item];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return [data, mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs))];
end;

bs_ngon_edgeconfl :=
proc(t1, t2)
    local e1, e2, c, seg;

    e1 := {op(1, t1)} union op(2, t1);
    e2 := {op(1, t2)} union op(2, t2);

    if nops(e1 union e2) <> 6 then return true fi;

    seg := [];

    for c to 3 do
        if op(1, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(2, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 1]
        elif op(2, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(3, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 2]
        else
            seg := [op(seg), 3];
        fi;
    od;

    evalb(not(seg[1] = seg[2] and seg[2] = seg[3]));
end;

bs_ngon_cycconfl :=
proc(c)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c) do
        for q from p+1 to nops(c) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c[p], c[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_cyc2confl :=
proc(c1, c2)
    option remember;
    local p, q;

    for p to nops(c1) do
        for q to nops(c2) do
            if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(c1[p], c2[q]) then
                return true;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    return false;
end;

bs_ngon_admissible :=
proc(n, cycs)
    local adms, item, nxtgen, cind, pos, res;

    if nops(cycs) = 0 then return 0 fi;

    adms := [ [1] ];

    for cind from 2 to nops(cycs) do
        nxtgen := [ [cind] ];

        for item in adms do
            for pos to nops(item) do
                if bs_ngon_cyc2confl
                (cycs[cind], cycs[item[pos]]) then
                    break;
                fi;
            od;

            if pos = nops(item) + 1 then
                nxtgen := [op(nxtgen), [op(item), cind]];
            fi;
        od;

        adms := [op(adms), 
                 seq(nxtgen[pos], pos=1..nops(nxtgen))];
    od;

    res := 0;

    for item in adms do
        if 3*add(nops(cycs[pos]), pos in item) = n then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths_task :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges_src, e, edges, autom, cargs,
    cycles, p;

    if type(n mod 3, positive) then return 0 fi;

    edges_src := convert(choose({seq(p, p=0..n-1)}, 3), list);

    edges := [];
    for e in edges_src do
        edges := [op(edges),
                  {e[3], {e[1], e[2]}},
                  {e[2], {e[1], e[3]}},
                  {e[1], {e[2], e[3]}}];
    od;

    cargs := [];

    for rot from 0 to n-1 do
        if rot > 0 then
            autom :=
            [seq({edges[p][1]+rot mod n,
                  {edges[p][2][1]+rot mod n,
                   edges[p][2][2]+rot mod n}},
                 p=1..nops(edges))];

            cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
            cycles :=
            select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

            cargs := [op(cargs), [n, cycles]];
        fi;

        autom :=
        [seq({n-1-(edges[p][1]+rot) mod n,
              {n-1-(edges[p][2][1]+rot) mod n,
               n-1-(edges[p][2][2]+rot) mod n}},
             p=1..nops(edges))];

        cycles := pet_autom2cyclesA(edges, autom);
        cycles :=
        select(c->not(bs_ngon_cycconfl(c)), cycles[1]);

        cargs := [op(cargs), [n, cycles]];
    od;

    Threads:-Task:-Continue
    (`+`, Tasks = [bs_ngon_admissible, seq(p, p in cargs)]);
end;

bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local res;

    res := Q(n, 3)+
    Threads:-Task:-Start(bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths_task, n);

    res/2/n;
end;
```

**Addendum Mon Jun  1 22:05:48 CEST 2015.** Here is a simple Maple routine that computes the first three nonzero values of $U(n,3)$ by total enumeration. They turn out to be $1, 4, 22$, which confirms the results from the application of Burnside's lemma. This seems to be about the limit where brute force is concerned.

```
with(combinat);

bs_ngon_edgeconfl :=
proc(t1, t2)
    local e1, e2, c, seg;

    e1 := {op(1, t1)} union op(2, t1);
    e2 := {op(1, t2)} union op(2, t2);

    if nops(e1 union e2) <> 6 then return true fi;

    seg := [];

    for c to 3 do
        if op(1, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(2, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 1]
        elif op(2, e1) < op(c, e2) and
        op(c, e2) < op(3, e1) then
            seg := [op(seg), 2]
        else
            seg := [op(seg), 3];
        fi;
    od;

    evalb(not(seg[1] = seg[2] and seg[2] = seg[3]));
end;


bs_ngon_eplanar3_paths :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local rot, edges_src, e, f, p, edges, res, selc, sel,
    item, admit, autom, sl;

    if type(n mod 3, positive) then return 0 fi;

    edges_src := choose([seq(p, p=0..n-1)], 3);

    edges := {};
    for e in edges_src do
        edges := {op(edges),
                  {e[3], {e[1], e[2]}},
                  {e[2], {e[1], e[3]}},
                  {e[1], {e[2], e[3]}}};
    od;

    sl := [];

    for rot from 0 to n-1 do
        sl := [op(sl), [seq(p=(p+rot) mod n, p=0..n-1)]];
        sl := [op(sl), [seq(p=(n-1-(p+rot)) mod n, p=0..n-1)]];
    od;

    res := {};

    selc := firstcomb(nops(edges), n/3);

    while type(selc, set) do
        sel := {seq(edges[selc[p]], p=1..n/3)};

        admit := true;

        for e to nops(sel) do
            for f from e+1 to nops(sel) do
                if bs_ngon_edgeconfl(sel[e], sel[f]) then
                    admit := false;
                fi;
            od;
        od;

        if admit then
            item := {};

            for p in sl do
                item := item union {subs(p, sel)};
            od;

            res := res union {item};
        fi;

        selc := nextcomb(selc, nops(edges));
    od;

    nops(res);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again Marko, your contribution to this problem is really great and very much appreciable :).

Comment: There are several alternatives now which you should feel free to decide on. We can go public, meaning submitting to the OEIS and possibly posting to MaplePrimes. Note that this would mean freezing the problem definition in its present state and opening a new question if the definition changes. Or if you don't want to go public yet you could eventually put a bounty on it which is another way to generate activity. I agree that we would all benefit from seeing an implementation in a different programming language. I suspect GAP could be quite helpful here which can also do parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences in Oeis related to this are those titled "noncrossing path sets". A302828 gives a table of $U(n,k)$ with column 3 and 4 being A303330 and A303867. Other sequences have been added for the cases of counting only distinct solutions up to rotation and also for mixed path lengths.

Noncrossing path sets are a subclass of noncrossing graphs. Other subclasses include noncrossing trees, forests and partitions and also dissections of a polygon by nonintersecting diagonals. There is much literature on some of these.

The method of solution requires the use of Burnsides' lemma. Firstly it is necessary to look at the number of symmetrical configurations of a single path. Rotation: A path on an odd number of nodes cannot have rotational symmetry, and for even $k$ the number of paths with $180$ degree rotational symmetry is $2^{k/2-1}$.  Reflection: For odd $k$, there are $2^{(k-3)/2}$ paths that are symmetrical and for even $k$, there are $2^{k/2-1}$ with the line symmetry drawn between the two central nodes. There is also a special case when $k=2$ of a line of symmetry connecting the two nodes.

It is easier to work with generating functions. In particular, if $g$ is the generating function for a class of combinatoric object (in this case, noncrossing path sets), then $g^2$, $g^3$, etc will give the generating function for an ordered pair, triple etc of those objects. Also $1/(1-g)$ is the generating function for a sequence of zero or more of such objects. Differentiating is a trick to multiply the $n^{th}$ term by $n$, and integration is a similar trick for dividing the $n^{th}$ term by $n$. A good introductory text on the use of generating functions for counting is Chapter 1 of Analytic Combinatorics by Flajolet and Sedgewick which available for free download.

The generating function for $Q$ is given by $1 + \text{serreverse}( x/(k*2^{k-3}*(1 + x)^k)$ where serreverse is series reversion. The $1$ at the beginning is important to also provide an option for an empty set. (when computing $g^r$ we typically want to allow some of the parts to be empty). For the case of $k=3$ this expands to $1 + 3*x + 27*x^2 + 324*x^3 + 4455*x^4 + 66339*x^5 ...$.

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. (sorry - it would take many illustrations to explain everything in a satisfactory way). Reference material: A similar problem is that of polygon dissection (some details differ).
1. F. Harary, E. M. Palmer and R. C. Read, [On the cell-growth problem for arbitrary polygons](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(75)90041-2), Discr. Math. 11 (1975), 371-389.
2. E. Krasko, A. Omelchenko, [Brown's Theorem and its Application for Enumeration of Dissections and Planar Trees](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v22i1p17), The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, 22 (2015), #P1.17. If those are a bit heavy, there is also a short note https://oeis.org/A175954/a175954.txt that deals with the case where paths cover either 1 or two nodes. (this note has a couple of egregious errors, but it covers the considerations are almost identical to those required for paths of longer length).