# How many ways to select $k$ vertices of an $n$-gon?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have a regular $n$-gon, of which I have to select $k$ vertices. The selections must be rotationally distinct; two selections would be considered equivalent if one is a rotation of the other. For example, if I have a square, and I want to select 2 vertices, there are only 2 possible ways to do that according to the constraint. One is "x - x -", another is "x x - -".

If we denote the function by $CR(n,k)$, then these are the trivial cases:

1. $CR(n, 1) = 1$
2. $CR(n, 2) = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$
3. $CR(n, k) = CR(n, n - k)$

I am quite short of ideas on how to find the recurrence or closed formula of this problem, or if this problem has any closed form / recurrence solution at all. Any help with a bit detailed walk through would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by selection must be rotationally invariant?

Comment: Supposing, I have a 4-gon and I have to select 2 vertices. Hence, these two selections are the same.
x-x-, 
-x-x. 
These selections are the same,
x--x, 
xx--, 
-xx-, 
--xx

Comment: The following [MSE meta link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has a section on enumerating necklaces and bracelets.

Comment: One way to think about this (perhaps the *best* way) is the [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of  cyclic rotations on the subsets of vertices.  Rotations preserve the number of vertices in a subset (obviously), so the counting comes down to counting *orbits* of the $k$-subsets of $n$-vertices under those rotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the OP seems interested in fixing  $k$ and letting $n$ vary we will
do an example to show how this might work.

By the Polya Enumeration Theorem what we have here is
$$[z^k] Z(C_n)(1+z)$$
with $Z(C_n)$ the cycle index of the cyclic group which is
$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

The desired quantity is thus given by
$$[z^k] Z(C_n)(1+z)
= [z^k] \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) (1+z^d)^{n/d}.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n, d|k} \varphi(d) [z^k] (1+z^d)^{n/d}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n, d|k} \varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|\gcd(n,k)} \varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d}.$$

For $k=4$ starting at $n=1$ we obtain the sequence
$$0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 10, 14, 22, 30, 43, 55, 73,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A008610](https://oeis.org/A008610) 
where we find confirmation.

Another interesting one is $k=6$ which yields
$$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 10, 22, 42, 80, 132, 217, 335, 504,\ldots$$
which points to [OEIS A032191](https://oeis.org/A032191).

A Maple session with these looks like this:

```
> with(numtheory):                                                         
> Q := (n,k) -> 1/n*add(phi(d)*binomial(n/d,k/d), d in divisors(gcd(n,k)));
Q := (n, k) -> add(numtheory:-phi(d) binomial(n/d, k/d),

    d  in  numtheory:-divisors(gcd(n, k)))/n

> seq(Q(n,8), n=1..18);                                                    
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 15, 43, 99, 217, 429, 810, 1430, 2438
```

which incidentally is [OEIS A032193](https://oeis.org/A032193).

Comment: It'll be a sin by my side not to refer you to my similiar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294224/number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-dots-in-a-perfect-n-gon . Perhaps you'll be able to help :) 
I apologize, OP! Really am!

Comment: I have been following your question for three hours. @Matan , felt really intrigued.

Comment: How wonderful to hear. Thanks! I update it on regular basis and work on it when I have time. Keep track of it :) @sarker306

Answer (score 2):

Taking the [necklace proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Necklaces) for Fermat's Little Theorem as inspiration:

For $n,k$ coprime, every possible selection has $n$ rotations. So

$$CR(n,k) = \frac 1n{n \choose k}$$

Otherwise letting $d=\gcd(n,k)$, we need to account for those choices where there is a repeat pattern smaller than $n$, which will be all possible choices over the shorter interval with the reduced number of choices (but repeated through the entire set):

$$\begin{align}
CR(n,k) &= \frac 1n\left[{n \choose k} - {n/d \choose k/d }\right] + CR\left(\frac nd, \frac kd \right) \\
&=\frac 1n\left[{n \choose k} - {n/d \choose k/d }\right] + \frac 1d {n/d \choose k/d } 
\end{align}$$

since $\gcd(\frac nd, \frac kd)=1$

And also note that $CR(n,0)=1$ and $CR(n,n)=1$.

Comment: Any explanation? Or any source where the derivation is explained?

Comment: Joffan, if you could please refer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294224/number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-dots-in-a-perfect-n-gon?rq=1 for a related problem I asked I will be grateful. Perhaps you'll be able to help.

Comment: @sarker306 If you review the [necklace proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Necklaces) of Fermat's Little theorem I think you'll understand where this comes from. If I have time I'll add to it.

Comment: I get CR(6,3) = 25/6 when I apply your solution.

Comment: CR(n, 2) has its correct value when n is odd, not even. But really thanks for bringing in this gcd issue, it seems to be a right step to the right direction, I didn't suspect it before. I'll think it through the night.

Comment: It overestimates sometimes, try n=10 and k=4. I don't think you're going to be able to capture the complexities of higher order symmetries without expressing your answer as a summation.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I think you're right, I need to scan through common prime factors or something.